# C Proxy crashing

Tags: c, sockets

Im writing a program which connects to a browser and sends the http request from the browser to a server, and then sends the response back to the browser, which loads the page with some of the content. My program sends things successfully and loads pages, but does not run continuously and will crash after a random amount of time- sometimes 10 seconds of running sometimes 1 minute. I want this proxy to be able to run forever. Below is how I have structured my code. I have included the recv and write section which I think is causing my errors in full. I am pretty new to socket programming and c In general and looking for some tips on my structure and anything I may have missed.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char ip[40]
    char *host = argv[1];
    char *port_s = argv[2];
    int err;                             
    int socket_browser, socket_newBrowser, c;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    int n;

    socket_browser= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socket_browser < 0)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    if (err = bind(socket_browser , (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) != 0)
    {
        resourceError(err, "bind");
        return 1;
    }

    if (err = listen(socket_browser , 3) != 0)
    {
        resourceError(err, "listen");
    }

while (1){

        c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        server_socket= accept(socket_browser, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t *)&c);

       char buf[256];
       int n;

       n = recv(socket_newBrowser, buf, 256, 0);
       if (n < 0){
          resourceError(n,"recv");
       }

      int server_socket;
      struct sockaddr_in server2;

       server_socket= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (server_socket < 0)
        {
            resourceError(server_socket, "serverSocket");
        }
        server2.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
        server2.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server2.sin_port = htons(80);

       connect(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server2, sizeof(server2))
       send(server_socket, buf, strlen(buf), 0);

      char reply[256];
      int bytes_reply = 0;

    do
            {
                bytes_reply = recv(server_socket, reply, sizeof(reply), 0);
                // Need to check for double enter as this currently does not work in telnet
                if (bytes_reply == -1)
                {
                    perror("Recv error");
                }
                else
                {
                    write(server_socket, reply, bytes_reply);
                }
            } while (bytes_reply > 0);


        printf("connections closed");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. It can instantly tell you the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. Please post that minimum of debug info.

Comment: Maybe it is running out of sockets? The `while (1)` loop does not close `socket_newBrowser` or `server_socket`, and does not check the result of the `accept` call and `socket` calls. (Also, where is `new_socket` defined?)

Comment: @kaylum firefox tells me -Paused on exception
SyntaxError: '*,:x' is not a valid selector

Comment: What port does your server want to `bind` to? You pass an unitialized `server` variable to `bind`.

Comment: @IanAbbott where would be an appropriate spot to close both sockets?

Comment: @Michael After the `do while` loop near the `printf("connections closed");` seems like a good place to close the sockets.

Comment: Your code just guesses which direction it needs to transfer next but if it ever guesses wrong, will hang indefinitely. What if your first `read` call doesn't receive the entire request? You will hang forever waiting to `recv` something from the server when you need to `recv` the rest of the request from the browser.

Comment: There are two ways you can make a proxy: 1) Make a proxy that understands the protocol it's proxying. 2) Make a proxy that doesn't make assumptions about what the protocol will do. Your code doesn't understand the protocol (it has no idea what an HTTP query looks like) but makes assumptions (like that its first `recv` call will be all the server needs to see in order to send a reply). That will never work except by luck.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem (or at least *a* problem) is:

```
n = recv(socket_newBrowser, buf, 256, 0);
/*versus*/
send(server_socket, buf, strlen(buf), 0);
```

`buf` is not null-terminated, you should have used the `n` value returned from recv instead of `strlen`.